# How do I start an executable jar from within a .sh script?

Tags: java, linux, shell, sh

I have an executable jar file that I would like to start from a *.sh script on Ubuntu Linux.

Currently the myapp.sh file looks like this (**error: "nothing happens"**) :

```
java -jar myapp.jar --start
```

I also tried (**error: "/bin/sh: 0: Can't open java"**):

```
/bin/sh java -jar myapp.jar --start
```

and (**error: "/bin/sh: 0: Can't open java -jar myapp.jar --start"**):

```
/bin/sh "java -jar myapp.jar --start"
```

the myapp.sh file has rwx permissions... when I call ./myapp.jar nothing happens.

does somebody has a solution to this issue ?

many thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: Here's my MANIFEST.MF :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_38-b05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: lib/gf-client.jar lib/security.jar lib/eclipselink-2.3.2.j
 ar lib/javax.persistence-2.0.3.jar lib/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jp
 ql_1.0.1.jar lib/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor-2.3.2
 .jar lib/javaee-api-6.0.jar lib/LawSuiteFXW.jar lib/AbsoluteLayout.ja
 r lib/beansbinding-1.2.1.jar lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar lib/antlr-runtime-3.
 3.jar lib/bootstrapconnector.jar lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar lib/common
 s-collections-3.2.1.jar lib/commons-compress-1.3.jar lib/commons-dige
 ster-1.7.jar lib/commons-email-1.2.jar lib/commons-io-2.4.jar lib/com
 mons-lang-2.4.jar lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1
 .jar lib/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar lib/glazedlists_java15-1.9-20111127.203
 634-11.jar lib/icepdf-core.jar lib/icepdf-viewer.jar lib/jasypt-1.9.0
 .jar lib/jcommon-1.0.17.jar lib/jfreechart-1.0.14.jar lib/jhall.jar l
 ib/jms.jar lib/joda-time-2.1.jar lib/junit-3.8.1.jar lib/log4j-1.2.15
 .jar lib/migcalendarbean.jar lib/PDFRenderer-0.9.1.jar lib/xmlsec-2.0
 .jar lib/avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar lib/avalon-framework-impl-4.3
 .1.jar lib/docx4j-2.8.1.jar lib/fop-1.0.jar lib/itext-2.1.7.jar lib/j
 axb-svg11-1.0.2.jar lib/jaxb-xmldsig-core-1.0.0.jar lib/jaxb-xslfo-1.
 0.1.jar lib/poi-3.8.jar lib/poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar lib/serializer-2.7
 .1.jar lib/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar lib/wmf2svg-0.9.0.jar lib/xalan-2
 .7.1.jar lib/xhtmlrenderer-1.0.0.jar lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar lib/xmlg
 raphics-commons-1.4.jar lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar lib/poi-ooxml-
 schemas-3.8-20120326.jar lib/batik-1.1.1.jar lib/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar lib/
 AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar lib/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar lib/swingx-beani
 nfo-1.6.4.jar lib/pdfbox-1.7.1.jar lib/fontbox-1.7.1.jar lib/jempbox-
 1.7.1.jar lib/jai_codec.jar lib/jai_core.jar lib/java-mail-1.4.6.jar 
 lib/LawSuiteSE.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: ch.acme.core.Main
```

EDIT 2:

I used the following code to start my GUI application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Main m = new Main();
            m.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Removing this to the following, solved the problem. Any ideas ???

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Did you define your `Main-Class` inside `MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: You haven't said what goes wrong with what you've shown...

Comment: Please type java -version

Comment: sure. MANIFEST.MF is set up properly. by typing "java -jar myapp.jar --start" to the terminal, the application works fine. this also answer the question if java is installed properly.

Comment: okay I added the error messages to the above trials... any help highly appreciated.

Comment: be sure that your java_home/bin is in the path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to start my GUI application:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Removing this, solved the problem. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Some stuff you might add to help us help you

- Show us the content of the JAR (Manifest)
- How you build your executable Jar (Maven?)

To be able to start an app from an executable Jar you need:

Define the Main-class inside the manifest
Define the class-path inside the manifest and inculde all dependency inside the jar
or
add -cp to the java call with path to classpath of your dependencies

EDIT: ok from the comments i understand the java command works fine... so your prob is with sh

add this to the top of your sh

## !/bin/ksh

and start it by typing ./scriptname.ksh

(replace ksh by sh if you absolutly need to run in sh)

Edit 2:
Sample of a Ksh i used:

```
#!/bin/ksh

JAVA_HOME16=/usr/java16/bin

${JAVA_HOME16}/java -Drunningenv=dev -Dbatch.jdbc.user=${DB2_CODE_USAGER}     -Dbatch.jdbc.password=${DB2_MOT_PASSE} -jar ${BASEDIR}/BD_PVFI/bin/spring-batch-    conciliation-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar input.desj.file=${INPUTFILE_DESJ}
rc=$?
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. #!/bin/ksh or !/bin/ksh ? I need sh, there is no ksh installed on my Ubuntu by default.

Comment: #!/bin/sh then.  this should do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try running java with the full path.

Run "which java" for figuring out the full path.